# image is not displaying in php pages

Tags: php, html, css

I created header and fix some images in `img` tag.
It is displaying in html page properly...

But when I save the page with `.php` extension only this 
single image cannot display other are displaying properly.
I placed my complete header code..but this images is not display in `.php` pages.
it works in html pages fine.

i check for src but this is also perfect.
the image is placed inside `bhaskarhindi/images` folder.
I am working on `localhost`

my url is like:
`bhaskarhindi/index.php`

```
 <div class="ad468x60"><a href="#"><img src="images/3017596584012930046.jpg" width="590px" height="100px" /></a></div>
```

Plz help to resolve this issue...

```
<!-- BEGIN header -->
  <div id="header">
    <ul>     
      <li class="f"><a href=""><img src="images/facebook.png" /></a></li>
     <li><a href=""><img src="images/twitter.png" /></a></li>
     <li><a href=""><img src="images/youtube.png" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="links">Subscribe: <a href="#">Sign-in</a> | <a href="#">Sign-up</a> | <a href="#">Advt. Rate Card</a> | <a href="#">E-Paper</a> | <a href="#">Email</a></p>
    <div class="break"></div>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1><a href="#"><img src="images/dainik_logo_new_outer.png" width="350" height="100" /></a></h1>
     <!-- <p>Free CSS Template</p>-->
    </div>
    <div class="ad468x60"><a href="#"><img src="images/3017596584012930046.jpg" width="590px" height="100px" /></a></div>
    <div class="break"></div>
  </div>
 <!-- END HEADER-->
```

Comment: Which image doesn't get displayed if you change the file extension to `*.php`?

Comment: you said it is working in html page, r u running that html directly or from localhost??

Comment: It could also be related to your CSS `class="ad468x60"`, so check your stylesheet and all paths. Add error checking.

Comment: Have you given it any thought as to why only the `.png` files are showing and the one that isn't is a `.jpg`? (wink) Check your server's configuration.

Comment: *"the image is placed inside bhaskarhindi/images folder"* - `<img src="bhaskarhindi/images/3017596584012930046.jpg"`

Comment: Yeah, I think Fred is right! ;)

Comment: Well @Rizier123, it looks like this one is *dead in the water*. Good luck to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is coming from the class name "ad468x60"..Please remove this class for the image to display.

Answer (score 0):

if the path mentioned in img tag is correct then there is no issue with the code and it shall display the image for you

and as you said it is working for html page and not working for php page if i am not wrong you might be directly opening html file (with out using server) and also if i am not wrong you might be using AD BLOCKER . . .

I suggest you to disable your ad blocker if any so that

```
<div class="ad468x60"><a href="#"><img src="images/3017596584012930046.jpg" width="590px" height="100px" /></a></div>
```

the above code works and your image will display when running through server . . .

and the reason why it is working with html file when opened directly is Adblocker only blocks divs coming from server

Answer (score 0):

Without writing image source,write only folder name in which image stored,forward slash and image name.
Eg-folder name/image name.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no difference between file extensions.As HTML is a client side  and PHP is server side.
So Your file name wont difference whether it will show the image or not.

Comment: This makes no sense, PHP generates a HTML page which is sent to the browser, and the browser requests the images: the browser sees no difference.